# Get lines Pandas with groupby ignoring NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get rows in my dataframe (using `.last_valid_index()`), but some of the indices which satisfy the condition are `NaN` (that's fine, as I may have some empty blocks between the `cuts`).

```
df.groupby('cuts').apply(lambda x: x.q1.last_valid_index())
Out[289]: 
cuts
(2016-04-29 23:59:59.999999999, 2016-05-14]     13.0
(2016-05-14, 2016-05-28]                        19.0
(2016-05-28, 2016-06-11]                         NaN
(2016-06-11, 2016-06-25]                         NaN
(2016-06-25, 2016-07-09]                         NaN
(2016-07-09, 2016-07-23]                        75.0
(2016-07-23, 2016-08-06]                         NaN
(2016-08-06, 2016-08-20]                         NaN
(2016-08-20, 2016-09-03]                         NaN
(2016-09-03, 2016-09-17]                       138.0
(2016-09-17, 2016-10-01]                         NaN
(2016-10-01, 2016-10-15]                       156.0
(2016-10-15, 2016-10-29]                         NaN
```

I need to get rid of NaNs, I tried something like:

```
df.groupby('cuts').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.q1.last_valid_index()] if (x.q1.last_valid_index() > 0)
```

but it didn't work.

I'm sure it should be very simple, but I'm struggling to find a neat solution.

**EDIT**

```
df[:50]
Out[305]: 
   response_date       q1  crp  ferritin     hb     q2  plasma  platelets  transferrin     q3    wcc   value             a1      a2      a3   a4
0     2016-04-27     34.0  6.1      15.3  136.0    NaN     1.0      404.0         27.0    NaN   9.33     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
1     2016-04-30      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN           12.0    0.98    80.0  1.0
2     2016-05-01      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN  1089.0            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
3     2016-05-02      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
4     2016-05-03      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
5     2016-05-04      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
6     2016-05-05      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
7     2016-05-06      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
8     2016-05-07      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
9     2016-05-08      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
10    2016-05-09      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
11    2016-05-10      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
12    2016-05-11      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
13    2016-05-12     38.0  1.1      11.1  135.0    4.0     1.0      382.0         18.0    5.0  10.60     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
14    2016-05-13      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
15    2016-05-14      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN           12.0    0.83    80.0  1.0
16    2016-05-15      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
17    2016-05-16      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
18    2016-05-17      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
19    2016-05-18     36.0  8.8      15.6  138.0    NaN     NaN      369.0         23.0    NaN   9.78     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
20    2016-05-19      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
21    2016-05-20      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
22    2016-05-21      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
23    2016-05-22      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
24    2016-05-23      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
25    2016-05-24      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
26    2016-05-25      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
27    2016-05-26      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
28    2016-05-27      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
29    2016-05-28      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN           14.0    1.60    80.0  1.0
30    2016-05-29      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
31    2016-05-30      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
32    2016-05-31      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
33    2016-06-01      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
34    2016-06-02      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN   802.0            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
35    2016-06-03      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
36    2016-06-04      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
37    2016-06-05      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
38    2016-06-06      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
39    2016-06-07      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
40    2016-06-08      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
41    2016-06-09      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
42    2016-06-10      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
43    2016-06-11      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN           13.0    1.40    75.0  1.0
44    2016-06-12      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
45    2016-06-13      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
46    2016-06-14      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
47    2016-06-15      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
48    2016-06-16      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
49    2016-06-17      NaN  NaN       NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN          NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN            NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
```

I need to extract data (blood results) between the dates of `a1`. I'm usind `pd.cut`, to get blocks between the dates of `a1`. If you notice, within some block of `a1`, there are not blood results, so this is how I got `NaN` previously. I need to get only rows with bloods between the dates of `a1`. However, there are might be more than one set of bloods between the dates, so this is why I'm taking the last set of results, which is closer to the end of the `a1` block.

Comment: Can you provide sample of your input data?

Comment: Why not just chain `.dropna()` after the groupby-apply statements? Like: `df.groupby('cuts').apply(lambda x: x.q1.last_valid_index()).dropna()`

Comment: I'm assuming the first data output you supply is what you want to achieve, aside from the NaN rows

Comment: @kev8484, ideally, I would like to get rows instead of their indices, x.loc[...], however, I can't supply x.loc[NaN].

Comment: using `df.index` `dropna` and `isin`